# Evaluate cells of strings in a cell array

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a cell array containing strings and cells, similar to this:

```
theCellArray = {{'aa1' {'bb'; 'cc'}}; {'aa2' {'dd'; 'ee'}}};
```

Now I would like to be able to concatenate the names and get something similar to this :

```
aa1.bb
aa1.cc
aa2.dd
aa2.ee
```

The number of element might change (so for `aa1`, there might be `bb`, `cc`, `dd`, `ee`, etc).

I tried various things, but I'm always unable to make Matlab evaluate the second step of string (the one containing `bb`, `cc`...). Any ideas?

EDIT:

There might be more than 2 levels, so `theCellArray` could be :

```
theCellArray = {{'aa1' {'bb' {'b1' {'b11' 'b12'} 'b2'}; 'cc'}}; {'aa2' {'dd'; 'ee'}}};
```

`theCellArray` is like a tree, so the number of level is unknown.

Comment: Is `aa1.bb` the string `'aa1.bb'` or a `struct` named `aa1` with fields named `'bb'` and `'cc'`?

Comment: @horcler `aa1.bb` should be a string `'aa1.bb'`

Comment: What is the final purpose of these names?

Comment: @OlegKomarov the names are just for he example. The real names correspond to input to simulink blocks. Since the structure can vary quite a bit, the cell doesn't always contains the same structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a recursive solution:

```
function t = recCat(s)
if ~iscell(s)
    t = s;
elseif size(s,1) > 1,
    t = [recCat(s(1,:)); recCat(s(2:end,:))];
elseif size(s,2) > 1,
    t0 = cellfun(@(x) strcat('.', x), ...
        cellfun(@recCat, s(2:end),  'UniformOutput', false),  ...
        'UniformOutput', false);
    t = strcat(s{1}, t0{:});
elseif ischar(s{1})
    t = s;
else
    t = recCat(s{1});
end
end
```

Here is the result for first example:

```
>> theCellArray = {{'aa1' {'bb'; 'cc'}}; {'aa2' {'dd'; 'ee'}}};
>> recCat(theCellArray)
ans = 
    'aa1.bb'
    'aa1.cc'
    'aa2.dd'
    'aa2.ee'
```

The second, as it stands now fails because of dimension issues in concatenation. I put `'bb' {'b1' {'b11' 'b12'} 'b2'}` into another cell so that it has the same number of columns as `'cc'` then you get

```
>> theCellArray = {{'aa1' {{'bb' {'b1' {'b11' 'b12'} 'b2'}}; 'cc'}}; {'aa2' {'dd'; 'ee'}}};
>> recCat(theCellArray)
ans = 
    'aa1.bb.b1.b11.b12.b2'
    'aa1.cc'
    'aa2.dd'
    'aa2.ee'
```

However, you probably meant `b11` and `b12` to be on the same column not row so in that case:

```
>> theCellArray = {{'aa1' {{'bb' {'b1' {'b11';'b12'} 'b2'}}; 'cc'}}; {'aa2' {'dd'; 'ee'}}};
>> recCat(theCellArray)
ans = 
    'aa1.bb.b1.b11.b2'
    'aa1.bb.b1.b12.b2'
    'aa1.cc'
    'aa2.dd'
    'aa2.ee'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sweet one:

```
out = cellfun(@(y) cellfun(@(x) [ y{1} '.' x],y{2},'UniformOutput',false),theCellArray,'UniformOutput',false)
out{:}
ans = 

    'aa1.bb'
    'aa1.cc'


ans = 

    'aa2.dd'
    'aa2.ee'
```

Super One liner! (but not very efficient)  And only works with original pose of question with 2 levels of cell strings.

Comment: It works great, but only if the cell arrays has two levels. See the edit in my question.

Comment: It won't be a one liner anymore, but you could use eval and supply the additional level var names that way. You could construct the str without a for loop if you get creative, but its one work around if you wanted to use most of the core idea